# Why use i<array.length in for loop

Tags: javascript

Why `i<array.length` rather than `i=array.length`
When I originally wrote my code, I told the for loop to go through the length of the array. I defined the for loop as `(var i = 0; i=array.length; i++)`. That created an infinite loop. The way to fix it is to set `i<array.length`. However, can somebody explain to me why? It feels as if the loop should continue to the end of the array. If I set it to less than the length of the array, how do I know that it has checked all of the numbers?

Thanks!

Note: Here is my code.

```js
var array = [3, 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, 89, 32];
var largest = 0;
for (var i = 0; i largest) {
  largest = array[i]
}
}
console.log(largest);
```

Comment: `i=array.length` is not even a comparison? Did you mean `i==array.length`?

Comment: because indexing starts at 0

Comment: You should have a look at the doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: This seems to be asking about why an idiom came to be popular.  That invites a lot of speculation.  If that's not what you're asking, maybe rephrase to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

if you write `i=array.length` then you SET length to `i` - not COMPARE (it is allways true (or cast to true -  except if number is zero). To compare you need write `i!=array.length` or `i!==array.length`. Second thing if you use `i` as index then is beter to use `i<array.length` because array elements are indexed from `0` to `length-1` and value i greater equal length will newer occure.

```js
let array = ['a','b','c'];
let i=3;

console.log('!==', i!==array.length );

console.log('!=', i!=array.length );

console.log('<', i<array.length );

console.log('=', i=array.length );
```

Comment: Don't you want `!==` instead of `===` for a before end of loop check?

Answer (score 1):

Because

`for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)`

means:

> `i = 0` i starts at 0 at the beginning of the `for-loop`
>
> `i < array.length` as long as `i` is less than array.length, we continue looping
>
> `i++` after each loop we increment i by 1 (i.e. i = i + 1)

When you replaced `i < array.length` by `i = array.length`, you are saying `let i = array.length` which is setting the value `i` to `array.length`. So long as the statement is true it will continue looping. That's why it's an infinite loop.

But I guess that was a typo, you really meant `i == array.length`. Still doesn't work, because all arrays start with index 0 (which is why `i = 0` to start). This means they end at index of `array.length - 1`.

Example:

```
arr = ["a","b","c"]; //arr[2] = "c", but arr.length = 3
```

So we if loop through `arr`, we need to stop at index `2`, not `3`

Answer (score 0):

the second argument in `for` defines the condition under which the loop should continue/stop. The reason why `i<array.length` is correct is that arrays in javascript are 0 based. So if you try to get `array[array.length]`, it is out of bounds by definition

Answer (score 0):

When setting `i=array.length` your loop condition is going to evaluate what is in `i`.  If the length of the array is greater than 0 it will be a truthy value, resulting in an infinite loop.  If it is 0, the loop body (statement) won't execute.

You are overwriting your step-variable -or- iterator variable, `i`, which is not what you want to do.  If anything you can:
`for (var i=0,n=array.length; i<n; i++)`; however, storing the array length in a variable is no longer necessary for performance optimization (I think browsers now optimize when converting JS to bytecode.

---

Refer to [MDN resource on for-loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) for more information; here's a snippet:

> ```
> for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
>    statement
> ```
>
> #### initialization
>
> An expression (including assignment expressions) or variable declaration. Typically used to initialize a counter variable. This expression may optionally declare new variables with var or let keywords. Variables declared with var are not local to the loop, i.e. they are in the same scope the for loop is in. Variables declared with let are local to the statement.
>
> The result of this expression is discarded.
>
> #### condition
>
> An expression to be evaluated before each loop iteration. If this expression evaluates to true, statement is executed. This conditional test is optional. If omitted, the condition always evaluates to true. If the expression evaluates to false, execution skips to the first expression following the for construct.
>
> #### final-expression
>
> An expression to be evaluated at the end of each loop iteration. This occurs before the next evaluation of condition. Generally used to update or increment the counter variable.
>
> #### statement
>
> A statement that is executed as long as the condition evaluates to true. To execute multiple statements within the loop, use a block statement ({ ... }) to group those statements. To execute no statement within the loop, use an empty statement (;).